# What percentage of CA state income tax may I assume is local?

Tags: income-tax, state-income-tax

I am a NRA in Columbus, Ohio. I am trying to file my Columbus income tax. Having had an internship in Palo Alto, CA for 3 months in summer my CA W2 from internship shows no local taxes paid. Therefore I owe Columbus for that sum. But on the state level, Ohio recognizes the state income tax I paid to CA and provides a credit for that sum in my Ohio tax return.

My question is, given that Palo Alto does not tax income separately but is probably getting a percentage from CA state taxes collected, may I show some percentage of my CA W2 state income tax as local tax and get a credit from Columbus? If yes, how can I find this percentage?

Comment: Are you sure you are considered a Columbus resident?

Comment: I am almost sure that I am considered a Columbus resident during the 3 months of internship. I have talked with a CPA about this issue.

Comment: You said you are "NRA", which I assume means non-resident alien. So you are either in the US for a small part of the year or you have student or exchange visitor status. I believe that such temporary status means you might not be a Columbus resident (or indeed, Ohio resident) at all during the year.

Comment: That is correct, I am a non-resident alien per federal taxes and have a student status. But per Ohio Income Tax form IT 1040 I am an Ohio resident.

Comment: Ohio defines tax resident of Ohio to be someone domiciled in Ohio. If you are an international student, then it is likely you are not domiciled in Ohio, even if you live there for a few years.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot assume anything when figuring your income taxes. Everything you claim must be documented.  If there is no item on the W-2 showing local income tax, then there was no local income tax. In some states they allow the local jurisdiction to tax income (for example Maryland), in other states they don't (for example Virginia).

There is no way to estimate how state level income tax money flows to a local jurisdiction.

If Ohio is going to credit you with paying a local income tax, they will want to see either the W-2 or the California income tax forms, or both.

Comment: I didn' t mean to assume some figures to fill the W2 according to my will. I just meant to ask whether there is a KNOWN percentage that I might not have heard of before that is used in these cases. The problem is in the municipality level. On the state level, my CA W2 has a positive number for the state income tax and Ohio credits me for that.